# Error 500.19 in server with IIS 10 after deployment a new version of a web services

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, iis-10, .net-4.6

I had a Web Service running in net 3.5 (I know, so old) and I migrate it to Net 4.6. I completed the migration in local, but when I deploy the web services in the server I get an 500.19 error. I review the log event, the traces, web.config... but I can´t figure out. Please, could you help me? Please, ask me for any extra information that you need as logs, traces, specifications, web.config,....

I provide de Trace Log (please, let me know what I have to search, I am not able to recognize the relevant parts)

TRACE (relevant part)

```
<failedRequest url="https://XXXX.com:443/Project/services.svc/method/?number=12345678"
               siteId="1570333581"
               appPoolId="project_AppPool"
               processId="2644"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500.19"
               triggerStatusCode="500.19"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-05-31T11:54:31.713Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="2644" ThreadID="3212"/>
  <Computer>hostname</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="SiteId">1570333581</Data>
  <Data Name="AppPoolId">project_AppPool</Data>
  <Data Name="ConnId">1610612819</Data>
  <Data Name="RawConnId">0</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestURL">https://XXXXX.com:443/project/services.svc/method/?number=12345678</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestVerb">GET</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

The Log Event doesn´t return any relevant. Just a line saying PerfNet misconfigured. I checked with another expert and he said is not relevant.

WEB CONFIG (relevant part)

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
          

          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
          </assemblies>

        </compilation>

<pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="true">
        <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      
</controls>
```

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

**TRACE EXTENDED**

```
<failedRequest url="https://project.xxxx.com:443/Solution/proyect.svc/getNumber/?number=12345678"
               siteId="1570333581"
               appPoolId="app_pool"
               processId="2644"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{8000009B-0003-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500.19"
               triggerStatusCode="500.19"
               timeTaken="0"
           xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
           >

 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">CustomErrorModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>

 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000054-0000-F100-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">19</Data>
  <Data Name="FileNameOrURL">500.htm</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
```

I tried to paste the relevant part of the web.config and the Traces, but my knowlegde is limited. Please, let me knw if you want another part.

**All Trace Log**
[All Trace Log](https://github.com/EliasMerabet/SampleTraceLog/blob/main/LogError500.19)

Many Thanks again.

Comment: "I completed the migration in local", so what exactly did you do? There are too many breaking changes, so see if you have resolved them all, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: @LexLi Well, I migrate my project to Net 4.6. Run it and does call by postman and it works normally. All of them on my computer I mean, but when deploy this web services in the server. I receive a 500 error. I have the request trace failed logs if you want to try to help me (500.19 error for example). The event viewer doesnt contain any relevant information. Many Thanks

Comment: please post more details information about your issue, such as detailed error message, log event, the traces, web.config.

Comment: @samwu . Many Thanks for your help. I tried to offer you the relevant parts of traces and web.config. But please, let me know if you need anything else. Many Thanks again

Comment: Is there hresult code in your error message? If so, you can refer to this link: [HTTP Error 500.19](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage). there is also a detailed module with error messages in the log of failed request tracking, please post that part of the content.

Comment: @samwu. The trace I recollected doesn´t have HRESULT field. The relevant part of this trace is already posted. The trace is so big to post here, if you need another specific part, please, let me know. Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the contents of the `Errors and Warnings `section in the failed request trace log.

Comment: Thanks @samwu. I post the information related with errors or warnings in the failed request trace log. I hope it help. Many thanks again.

Comment: Not the content above, its location is under -Request Summary.

Comment: @samwu. Strange... It doesn´t have that section... I tried in 5 different Failed Request Trace Log and no one has it

Comment: Can you attach the xml file to the question?

Comment: Hi @samwu. Do you mean all log? It is massive to add it to this question.

Comment: I mean upload it to github and provide the GitHub link in the question.

Comment: The log is incorrect, the location of the log for failed request tracking should be `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\Logs\FailedReqLogFiles`, please recheck.

Comment: @samwu. Strange... I ad them from that path. I just did a double check and it is indeed the path. What could be happening?

Comment: Did you fix this : `\\?\D:\apps\solution1\proyect1\web.config ( 9) :There is a duplicate &apos;system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler&apos; section defined` If not this will prevent your application from starting.

Comment: Are you using the failed request tracer correctly? Or you can refer to this link: [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: @samwu. Yes, I exactly did like the link you provided me... Still strange... I am generating the logs but as far as you said not the proper one... What can I do wrong? Many Thanks again

Comment: In W3SVC* folder, there will be 2 files, the file you need to post is similar to `fr000001.xml`, please check if it is correct.

Comment: Hi @samwu. The file I posted is named fr011087.xml. It looks like the correct one. Could it be capped?

Comment: The fr000001.xml file name starts from 1 and increases sequentially, which means you have at least 11087 xml files, which does not seem reasonable, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Many thanks @samwu for your efford.